# Validate Spring XML schemas against XSDs from classpath

Tags: spring

Can anyone tell me what the best strategy to validate a spring configuration file against the spring-beans.xsd that is included with the spring-beans.jar. Can I have the schemaLocation in the XML header reference file:/org/springframework/beans/factory/xml/spring-beans-2.0.xsd?

Answer (score 1):

The best way is to use the Spring IDE and it will perform the validation during dev time. Also, spring auto validates all the config files (from the XSD that comes bundled with the jars) while it is loading them.

Comment: I saw that there is a file called spring.schema inside of the META-INF direcotry in the spring beans jar. This seems to point toward http://www.springframework.org/ for schema locations. Do you know if this file is used at runtime?

Answer (score 1):

ok here is the deal.... Eclipse uses plugins like spring IDE or spring STS that have spring bean validators in them.

There is an issue When the new versions of spring components come out the xsds do not appear to be in the eclipse plugins validators ahead of time. So eventually they create bug or enhancement requests in the projects JIRA system and they are put in in a new release/update. You can vote on these bugs to let them know there is demand to get them in faster.

There is also a work around to use in the interim in this old blog post by Craig Walls

http://www.springone2gx.com/blog/craig_walls/2007/08/fixing_spring_modules_xsd_errors_in_eclipse